# Robust and Accurate IIS Reporting tool for fail over IIS Services

Tags: iis-6, logging, report, w3c, web-farm

Good day,

I need to be able to produce IIS usage reports for our SharePoint 2007 Custom application. The application runs on 2 IIS 6 Service farm for load balance/fail over purposes.

Here is the list of requirements that my management poses:

1.Daily Visitors (per farm). 
 2.Daily Hits (per farm). 
 3.Daily activity (hits, page views, visitors, avg. session duration). 
 4.Activity by hour of Day (for the whole farm). 
 5.Activity by day of week (for the whole farm combined). 
 6.Activity by month. 
 7.Page access statistics / Most popular pages. 
 8.Top authenticated users. 
 9.Browser use statistics. 
 10.Client OS Use statistics.

So I need to combine report results from the 2 IIS Boxes on the load balanced rotation.

So far I have tried these tools.:

1.`Web Log Expert` - produces desired report types, can combine IIS logs from multiple locations. But the tool has some major bugs, such as: 
  a. some important information is being missed from the report: in authenticated user report the test user I log into the application is missing from the report, the user is not specified in the ignore filter and that user is found in the ISS logs.
  b. Bug with time and dates. Even though there is an option to adjust the time from GMT to whatever, that changes is not being obeyed by the software. It can be fixed however by converting the W3C standard log files into `ncsa` format with `convlog` utility. However, in this case, the Browser and OS usage data is gone and lost from the report. 
2. `Samurize` - I am a bit perplexed with configuring it to report on the W3C log files. There is a lack of good tutorials or other information on that software as well.

Please recommend the tools that worked out for you and ideally answer at least a number of specified requirements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nintex has a program - no idea if it's any good (but their workflow does rock).